# Что делает эта команда?

Tags: linux, bash, gcc

В скобках компилятору нужно подсунуть libgcc. С хостовой машины? Я запутался, кто собирал LFS, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
cat gcc/limitx.h gcc/glimits.h gcc/limity.h > \
  `dirname $(x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -print-libgcc-file-name)`/install-tools/include/limits.h
```

Answer (score 4):

cat - распечатать содержимое файла. Если файлов несколько - они печатаются один за одним. В данном случае печатаются файлы gcc/limitx.h gcc/glimits.h gcc/limity.h

Дальше символ `>` - это перенаправление вывода, в данном случае в отдельный файл, имя которого определяется выражением

```
`dirname $(x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -print-libgcc-file-name)`/install-tools/include/limits.h
```

этот кусок состоит из двух частей. то, что в обратных кавычках - это команда, которую нужно выполнить и результат подставить вместо этого. Она вычисляет имя директории (каталога). Внутри ещё одна конструкция `$(...)` - которая делает ровно то же - запускает команду и подставляет ее вывод.

слеш после `>` - это просто разрыв длинной строки.

Comment: Самое главное забыли сказать - что команда сливает три файла вместе и кладет в одном месте.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, что значит «сливает» и «кладет»? `cat` делает именно то, что написал KoVadim — печатает содержимое файлов в `stdin` один за одним, а уже `>` перенаправляет вывод в другой файл.

Comment: Вы описываете элементы. А в целом операция состоит в создании нового файла, который содержит конкатенацию трёх исходных. Для пользователя важно именно это, а не то какими инструментами получен результат. Я, наверно, плохо объясняю.

Comment: Со вчера вопрос так изменился, что наше обсуждение потеряло смысл.

Comment: Ваше обсуждение имело смысл. Для меня (очень возможно, что и для кого-то еще) оно оказалось полезным. Спасибо.